# What are some languages that have largest set of characters?

Tags: writing-systems

What are some languages that have largest set of letters (like alphabet or kanji) aside from Chinese and Japanese?

Comment: Sui, Yi, Zhuang, Korean, Sumerian, Egyptian, Sanskrit, Ge'ez.

Comment: English has a lot of characters: Darth Vader, Robin Hood, Sherlock Holmes, Macbeth, Bart Simpson, Walter White...

Comment: @curiousdannii  Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure what my question comes off like, but by "characters," I meant "letters" like alphabet. Isn't that obvious or is that just a friendly joke? Sorry if it was confusing, but I'm just surprised! Is jknappen voting down because my question seems like about fiction characters?

Comment: @stacko Your question is fine, no one would actually be confused about it, but it's still fun to joke sometimes :)

Comment: @curiousdannii That's a relief! I thought that my question looked super strange or something. :)

Comment: @jknappen Sorry, why is this not a question on linguistics? It involves languages and it has the tag "writing-system" that is available here?

Comment: The real problem IMO is that (1) it relies on an undefined notion of "character" and (2) it asks for "some of the most". For any scale, *any* value is "one of the most", also "one of the least". Asking for "the top 4" avoids that vagarity.

Comment: Thanks, @user6726 for pointing those out! I thought of specifying that I need the very top or the top x, but then I thought the very top would be obviously Chinese. And I didn't have an idea on how many languages have alphabet kind of character library including punctuation (not including the irrelevant unicode symbols available when typing in those languages, of course) that have over 1.5 x types of characters compared to English. If there are too many, it'd be hard to list, but if there are only 15, I don't want to limit the number by saying I only need the top 10.

Comment: @user6726 Honestly, your first comment has satisfied my interest enough already, but do I have a way to avoid down-voting or votes to close once I got an answer in the comments? I often get down-votes here and I often get a warning message when posting questions that says I might be blocked if I post more questions with down-votes or votes to close.

Comment: @stacko, those are questions best suited for Meta.